Server Error: Next.js (14.2.6) is outdated (Turbo Error)
just wanted to initialize a turborepo and install tailwind css in the nextJs app.
But the tailwind css installation is causing an some error.
Firstly I installed the turborepo using
npx create-turbo@latest


Selected npm as the package manager.
Went inside the apps folder, and deleted the one of the two nextjs folder, then I renamed the remaining folder to user-app and tried to install tailwind css in it.
Followed the steps mentioned here. (I have followed all the steps)
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs .
After running these commands
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p


I get,
added 39 packages, and audited 708 packages in 3s

196 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

Created Tailwind CSS config file: tailwind.config.js
Created PostCSS config file: postcss.config.js


And then I ran the audit command npm audit
npm audit
npm WARN workspaces web in filter set, but no workspace folder present
# npm audit report

next  10.0.0 - 14.2.9
Severity: high
Next.js Cache Poisoning - <https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-gp8f-8m3g-qvj9>
Denial of Service condition in Next.js image optimization - <https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-g77x-44xx-532m>
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install next@14.2.16, which is outside the stated dependency range
node_modules/next

1 high severity vulnerability

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix --force


After running npm run dev
I get this error in the browser, image link https://ibb.co/sy8Hd9F
Next.js (14.2.6) is outdated (learn more) (turbo)
Server Error
Error: failed to receive message

Caused by:
- reading packet data
- Connection reset by peer (os error 104)

Debug info:
- Execution of get_written_endpoint_with_issues failed
- Execution of <AppEndpoint as Endpoint>::write_to_disk failed
- Execution of Project::emit_all_output_assets failed
- Execution of VersionedContentMap::insert_output_assets failed
- Execution of all_assets_from_entries failed
- Execution of AppEndpointOutput::output_assets failed
- Execution of AppEndpoint::output failed
- Execution of ClientReferenceGraph::entry failed
- Execution of ClientReferenceGraph::new failed
- Execution of primary_referenced_modules failed
- Execution of <ModuleCssAsset as Module>::references failed
- Execution of ModuleCssAsset::module_references failed
- Execution of ModuleCssAsset::classes failed
- Execution of process_css_with_placeholder failed
- Execution of parse_css failed
- Execution of <PostCssTransformedAsset as Asset>::content failed
- Execution of PostCssTransformedAsset::process failed
- failed to receive message
- reading packet data
- Connection reset by peer (os error 104)

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.


